# add carrier name in dropdown same as Fedex and etc

Tags: magento-1.8, shipment, shipment-tracking

Want to add the carrier name in dropdown same as default carriers in shipment admin panel, how can I set it ?

Please see picture

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

each carrier must have a model associated to it that implements the interface `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`. This interface has 2 methods.

```
interface Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

/**
 * Check if carrier has shipping tracking option available
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isTrackingAvailable();

/**
 * Get allowed shipping methods
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllowedMethods();

}
```

You have to implement the method `isTrackingAvailable` and make it return `true`. IN the dropdown you see in the backend only the carriers that have tracking available are listed.

Comment: Great, it work!

Comment: @sIiiS : Can you tell me which file you have edited or the full process to do this?

Comment: @Kishor: in my carrier Model file

Comment: Working for magento 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new active/inactive carrier in config

```
<default>
        <carriers>
            <your_carrier>
                <active>0|1</active>
                <model>your_module/your_carrier</model>
                <title>Your Carrier</title>
                <name>your_carrier</name>
                <price>0.00</price>
            </your_carrier>
        </carriers>
</default>
```

Then in your model your_module/your_carrier which extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract, rewrite the method isTrackingAvailable to return true:

```
public function isTrackingAvailable()
{
    return true;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26335950/1028804)